# Fit flex parent cross-axis to items

Tags: css, flexbox

Where the parent has `display: flex; flex-direction: column`, is it possible to make the parent's width expand to fit a flex item wider than the parent?

It's worth noting that the grandparent does **not** have `display: flex` nor a fixed width. It has a `min-width: 100%` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, and by using `inline-flex` instead of `flex`, it will grow with the child.

The reason why the *flex parent* won't grow along with its child when using `flex` is because `flex` work similar to a block element, and block element won't grow larger than its parent, which inline element does.

This can be seen here, where the grand `parent`, with or w/o `min-width: 100%`, won't grow with its content, but the `inline-flex` will. This would also be the case if the `flex` element would instead have `inline-block`.

Still, the `parent`'s content will overflow and effect its surroundings as if it would grow with content, and make the outer scroll to show up.

*Why the `parent` with `min-width` is slightly wider is because of the `padding` not being included in its set width, so adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to its rule will make them equal wide.*

Stack snippet

```css
.parent {
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}

.parent.with-min-width {
  min-width: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

.flex .item {
  width: 800px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent with-min-width">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `inline-flex` on the parent instead of `flex` and `inline-block` on the grandparent should do the trick.

Example B shows the modifications. If the img is wider than the viewport the parent and the grandparent will accommodate it (shrink your window down so img is wider than the viewport then scroll right).

```css
html,body {
  width: auto;
}

.grandparent {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.exampleB .grandparent {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.exampleB .parent {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="exampleA">
  <div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        <img src="//placehold.it/500x100"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<br/>

<section class="exampleB">
  <div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        <img src="//placehold.it/500x100"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I updated the question. The grandparent has `min-width: 100%` and `width: auto`. So if all parents of the `.parent` element are not fixed width, it should work as expected?

Comment: I'm still trying to get a handle on what you're expecting.  You have grandparent with a min-width of 100%;  You're justing wanting parent to fill that?  And where does the img width come into play?

Comment: If the `<img>` is not wider than the window, the `min-width: 100%` of `.grandparent` is used. If the `<img>` is wider than the window, all parents should expand to the width of the image.

Comment: And img is not auto width?  it extends past the viewport in that case?

Comment: In my scenario, the flex item has responsive contents that may exceed the window width. When that occurs, all parents (including the immediate flex parent) should expand to be the same width as said flex item.

Comment: "responsive" could mean many things.  It could be fluid with auto width, you could have media queries and breakpoints in place.  All of this could effect the outcome.  I think it would be best if you revised your question with an example of your actual content and it's CSS in a stack snippet, with a more descriptive question for that specific scenario.

Comment: I should've left that out, because the fluidity is controlled by Javascript. So in the eyes of CSS, it's a static width. Is it impossible to combine `min-width: 100%` and some kind of "fit to items wider than me" property?

Comment: I think I found your solution. Check the edited answer.

Comment: I need the `.parent` element to be a flexbox. Would `display: inline-flex` work too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158983/discussion-between-robert-wade-and-aleclarson).